# Есть ли смысл использовать Hadoop/mapreduce на одном компьютере

Tags: hadoop

Задаюсь вопросом есть ли смысл использовать Hadoop/mapreduce на одном компьютере. Нужно посылать запросы на сервер, который обрабатывает их за 0.2 секунды, но само общение с сервером при обработке запроса занимает 2 секунды. То есть, получаем 4килобайта данных за 2 секунды, что за 10 часов даёт около 70 мегабайт. Хотелось бы запустись 10 процессов, выполняющих эту программу, чтобы за те же 10 часов получать хотя бы 700 мегабайт. Hadoop хотелось бы использовать потому что он способен сам контролировать многопоточность и код написать просто полегче, так как ещё был опыт его использовать. Но опыт был его использовать имея под контролем несколько машин, а тут один MacBook Pro 2014 года. В сети натыкаюсь на отзывы о том, что использовать Hadoop без реально больших данных немного смысла, а у меня опыта не так много, чтобы решить.
Могут ли посоветовать знающие люди, сильный ли прирост продуктивности даст запуск программы на единственном компе с hadoop и какие ещё могут быть варианты?

Comment: "сильный ли прирост продуктивности" по сравнению с чем?

Comment: напишите просто обработку в несколько потоков. Hadoop тут ни к чему.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще никакого смысла,будет все гораздо медленнее работать. Используйте лучше многопоточность в вашем случае.

Hadoop предназначен для обработки больших массивов данных и достигается это за ***счет параллелизации обработки,а не за счет какого-то волшебного суперкода или еще чего.*** На маленьких объемах это только тормозит.

Для сравнения можете запустить скрипт Pig на каком-нибудь небольшом файле (~ 512MB) в локальном режиме (pig -x local) и на вырожденном кластере (pseudo distributed,ваш случай). Гарантирую,вы будете сильно удивлены разнице.